# Multirows pair-wised comparison of identifiers

Tags: r, match

After having bound two larges dataframes for the purpose of record linkage, I want to check the identifiers matching process.
My first data output looks like this:

```
id1 <- c("a1", "a1", "b1", "b1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "d1", "d1", "e1", "e1", "e1", "e1", "f1", "f1")
id2 <- c("123", "123", "456", "695", "252", "252", "252", "98521", "98521", "895", "895", "9856", "895", "9853", "9853")
df1 <- data.frame (id1, id2)

> df1
   id1   id2
1   a1   123
2   a1   123
3   b1   456
4   b1   695
5   c1   252
6   c1   252
7   c1   252
8   d1 98521
9   d1 98521
10  e1   895
11  e1   895
12  e1  9856
13  e1   895
14  f1  9853
15  f1  9853
```

I want to extract in a new df both identifiers whose match is not consistent such displayed below.

```
id1 <- c("b1", "b1", "e1", "e1", "e1", "e1")
id2 <- c("456", "695", "895", "895", "9856", "895")
df2 <- data.frame (id1, id2)

> df2
  id1  id2
1  b1  456
2  b1  695
3  e1  895
4  e1  895
5  e1 9856
6  e1  895
```

I can't figure out how to do this as the number of "pairs" is not constant and the unmatch is at a random position.

An output like this is also an acceptable option:

```
id1 <- c("a1", "a1", "b1", "b1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "d1", "d1", "e1", "e1", "e1", "e1", "f1", "f1")
id2 <- c("123", "123", "456", "695", "252", "252", "252", "98521", "98521", "895", "895", "9856", "895", "9853", "9853")
concord <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
df3 <- data.frame (id1, id2, concord)

> df3
   id1   id2 concord
1   a1   123    TRUE
2   a1   123    TRUE
3   b1   456   FALSE
4   b1   695   FALSE
5   c1   252    TRUE
6   c1   252    TRUE
7   c1   252    TRUE
8   d1 98521    TRUE
9   d1 98521    TRUE
10  e1   895   FALSE
11  e1   895   FALSE
12  e1  9856   FALSE
13  e1   895   FALSE
14  f1  9853    TRUE
15  f1  9853    TRUE
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

#### base R

```r
df1$concord <- ave(df1$id2, df1$id1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1
```

#### dplyr

You can use `dplyr::n_distinct`, a wrapper for `length(unique(x))`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  mutate(concord = n_distinct(id2) == 1)
```

#### output

```r
   id1   id2   concord
 1 a1    123   TRUE   
 2 a1    123   TRUE   
 3 b1    456   FALSE  
 4 b1    695   FALSE  
 5 c1    252   TRUE   
 6 c1    252   TRUE   
 7 c1    252   TRUE   
 8 d1    98521 TRUE   
 9 d1    98521 TRUE   
10 e1    895   FALSE  
11 e1    895   FALSE  
12 e1    9856  FALSE  
13 e1    895   FALSE  
14 f1    9853  TRUE   
15 f1    9853  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

**Base R approach**

This can be achieved by splitting `df1` by `id1` and then check for each `id1` consists of >1 `unique` case per `id1`. Because `split` returns a list, we can exploit `lapply` to perform the task on each element of that list. As the output of `lapply` is a list as well, we can use `do.call` to perform a task to the entire list at once (here: combine by rows, `rbind`).

```
out <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(split(df1, df1$id1), function(x) cbind(x, concord = nrow(unique(x)) < 2))
)
rownames(out) <- NULL # optional
```

**Output**

```
> head(out)
  id1 id2 concord
1  a1 123    TRUE
2  a1 123    TRUE
3  b1 456   FALSE
4  b1 695   FALSE
5  c1 252    TRUE
6  c1 252    TRUE
```